# zend form float and integer validation

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

I am using zend form. I want to validate a field and want to allow only flat and integer values in the field. It means user can either enter any floating value like `2.0 or 3.56, etc` OR `4 or 7, etc`. But I dont want to receive `alpha numeric or alphabet input`.

I have used `digit` validator but it only allows `digits` not `floating number`.

Can any body tell me how to put both validations together?

My code is as follows

```
$parent_affiliate_commission = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('parent_affiliate_commission');
$parent_affiliate_commission->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addValidator('Digits')
            ->setAttrib('class', 'small')
            ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(2, 100))
            ->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper', 'errors'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be really easy to create and use a [custom validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html). You could validate simply by using PHP is_int and is_float functions and still do in the 'Zend way'.

Answer (score 0):

By using the callback method I have validated the value in numeric.Because it will not allow the characters.

```
$inputFilter->add(
                $factory->createInput(
                        array(
                                'name' => 'proximity',
                                'required' => true,
                                'validators' => array(
                                        array(
                                                'name' => 'Callback',
                                                'options' => array(
                                                        'messages' => array(
                                                                \Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'The proximity value should be numbers'
                                                        ),
                                                        'callback' => function  (
                                                                $value, 
                                                                $context = array())
                                                        {
                                                            $isValid = is_numeric(
                                                                    $value);
                                                            return $isValid;
                                                        }
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )));
```